# Google Map onMapClickListener

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I am using clustering to draw markers on a map.

In some cases, I need to prevent close markers from being clustered.

To do this, I draw them separately.

By default, when I open the map, I set as cluster

```
override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {
        googleMap = map
        googleMap?.uiSettings?.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true
        googleMap?.uiSettings?.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
        googleMap?.uiSettings?.isCompassEnabled = true
        googleMap?.let {
            setupCluster(googleMap!!)
        }
        googleMap?.setOnMapClickListener {
            if (viewModel.isClient) {
                viewModel.setType(MapNewTwoViewModel.OrderType.MyOrders())
            } else
                viewModel.setType(MapNewTwoViewModel.OrderType.AllOrders())

        }
}

private fun setupCluster(map: GoogleMap) {
        clusterManager = ClusterManager(MyApplication.applicationContext(), map)
        renderer = DotRenderer()
        clusterManager?.renderer = renderer
        map.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager)
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager)
        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(clusterManager)
        clusterManager?.setOnClusterClickListener(this)
        clusterManager?.setOnClusterItemClickListener(this)
    }
```

i.e. markerClickLister and other Listeners are controlled by ClusterManager.

Sometimes I submit a single order via Bundle, which should not be clusterable

```
private fun setSingleOrder(orders: List<OrderX>?) {
        if(!orders.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Log.d("Marker", "3")
            
            googleMap?.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(null)
            googleMap?.setOnMarkerClickListener(null)
            googleMap?.setOnMarkerClickListener {
                Log.d("Marker", "1")
                for((id, or) in allOrders.entries){
                    Log.d(id, or.toString())
                }
                Log.d("Marker", "2")
                Log.d("Marker Snippet", it.snippet.toString())
                val singleOrders = listOf(allOrders[it.snippet.toString()]!!)
                viewModel.setType(MapNewTwoViewModel.OrderType.SingleOrder(), singleOrders)
                showBottomSheetOrders()
                true
            }
            Log.d("Marker", "4")
            val line = PolylineOptions()
            allOrders[orders[0].id.toString()] = orders[0]

            for (dot in orders[0].dots) {
                allDots[dot.id] = DotXPosition(dot, dot.position, orders[0].isMyOrder)
                val marker = MarkerOptions()
                    .position(dot.position)
                    .snippet(orders[0].id.toString())
                    .icon(getItemIcon(dot))
                val markerMap = googleMap?.addMarker(marker)
                markerMap?.let {
                    markerMap.snippet = orders[0].id.toString()
                    markersSingleOrder.add(markerMap)
                }
                line.add(dot.position)

            }
            stylePolyline(line, orders[0].isMyOrder)
            val currPolyline = googleMap?.addPolyline(line)
            currPolyline?.let {
                allPolylines[orders[0].id.toString()] = currPolyline
            }


        }
    }
```

I'm trying to override markerClickListener, but nothing happens when the marker is clicked. It seems that it is still controlled by the ClusterManager, and since there are no orders there, they will not be drawn.

Tell me how to solve this problem, for several days I can not think of anything

Comment: You'll need to extend `MarkerManager` and supply it in the `ClusterManager` constructor; then implement (override) `onMarkerClick` and look at the marker (tag field e.g.) and determine if it's one of your special markers; if not then call `super()` ; otherwise do something special.  (a little bit of work but essentially you are intercepting the click within the marker manager).

Comment: @Andy How does this help me?

If I add my layouts, which should not be subject to clustering, to the cluster (Now they are rendered separately), then they will undergo clustering

Comment: No - the clustermanager sees all marker clicks - even non-clustered - (there is only one marker listerner per map) - this intercepts it's marker listener to discover your markers and handle as needed.  I see you solved it anyways - so that is good.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way.

In ClusterManager, I add all the points, but when I need them not to be clustered, I just change the condition in shouldRenderAsCluster to impossible

```
override fun shouldRenderAsCluster(cluster: Cluster<DotX>): Boolean {
            return cluster.size > COUNT_POINT_FOR_RENDER_IN_CLUSTER
        }

viewModel.mediatorLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            Log.d("MediatorLiveData size", it.size.toString())
            if(viewModel.isSingleOrders)
                COUNT_POINT_FOR_RENDER_IN_CLUSTER = Int.MAX_VALUE
            else
                COUNT_POINT_FOR_RENDER_IN_CLUSTER = 1
            setItemsCluster(it)
        })
```